# Determine top t values with few calls to order(), a given procedure to order k values

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I tried to write a decent answer to [Most efficient way to get the largest 3 elements of an array using no comparisons but a procedure for ordering 5 elements descendantly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52713266/3789665).
I could not come up with something concise, let alone compelling.
I assumed duplicate values were allowed; unique values allowing "multidimensional trickery", code would probably end up more involved, still.

I coded around `order()` ordering non-descendingly; one thing nagging me is I might have been better off choosing non-ascendingly.

```
package net.reserves.human.coder.greybeard.sandbox;

import java.util.Arrays;

/** Determine top t values given a procedure to order k values. */
// currently for t < k; thinking k =(<) t gets (much) more complicated, still
public class TopByOrderK<E> {
    /** <code>apply(values, first, count)</code>
     *  orders <code>count</code> values in <code>E [] values</code>
     *  from <code>first</code> non-descendingly. */
    public interface OrderK<E> {
        /** <code>apply(values, first, count)</code>
         *  orders <code>count</code> values in <code>E [] values</code>
         *  from <code>first</code> non-descendingly. */
        public default void apply(E[] values, int offset, int k) {
            Arrays.sort(values, offset, offset + k);
        }
    }

    public TopByOrderK(int top, int k, OrderK<E> order) {
        if (k <= top)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of values"
                + " that can be ordered by a single call shall exceed"
                + " the number of top values to determine.");
        this.t = top;
        t_ = top -1;
        this.k = k;
        k_ = k - 1;
        k_t = k - top;
        this.order = null == order ? new OrderK<E>() {} : order;
    }
    OrderK<E> order;
    int calls;
    void orderK(E[] values, int offset) {
        calls += 1;
        order.apply(values, offset, k);
    }
    
    int offsets[], t, t_, k, k_, k_t;
    E[] candidates[];
    E nonTopT;
    
    /** From <code>valid</code> valid values
     *  in <code>candidates[--keep]</code>, distribute up to 
     *  <code>keep</code> values to this and "lower priority"
     *  <code>candidates</code> arrays */
    void keep(int keep, int valid) {
        final E values[] = candidates[--keep];
        orderK(values, 0);
        nonTopT = values[0];
        int down = k_ - keep;
        while (0 <= --keep && 0 < --valid) {
            candidates[keep][offsets[keep]]
                = values[down + keep];
            if (k <= (offsets[keep] += 1)) {
                if (0 < keep)
                    keep(keep, k);
                else {
                    orderK(candidates[0], 0);
                    candidates[0][0] = candidates[0][k_];
                }
                offsets[keep] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Determine top t values given a procedure to order k values. */
    // ToDo: define *determine*; currently: Leave in decreasing priority
    //                                            in candidates[t_]
    // currently for t < k; k =(<) t gets (much) more complicated, still
    // main idea: comparing values known to be smaller than t-1 values,
    // only one needs to be kept; <t-2: 2, ...
    // compare values of same "potential rank" up to some wrap-up.
    public void topByOrderK(final E[] many) {
        final int n = many.length;
        if (n < t)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("number of values supplied"
                + " may not be less than number of result values required.");
        // keep up to k values of each potential rank ...
        candidates = (E[][]) new Object[t][];
                          // java.lang.reflect.
                          // Array.newInstance(many.getClass(), t);
        for (int ci = candidates.length ; 0 <= --ci ; )
            candidates[ci] = Arrays.copyOf(many, k);
        if (n <= k) {  // one application of orderK should suffice
            handleFew(many);
            return;
        }
        // ... and next free offset
        offsets = new int[t];
        
        candidates[t_][k_] = many[0];  // arraycopy in loop will fill 0:k_
        int offset = 1;                // used in wrap-up
        for ( ; offset <= n - k ; offset += k_) {
            System.arraycopy(many, offset, candidates[t_], 0, k_);
            keep(t, k);
        }
        for (int left = n - offset ; 0 < left ; left = 0) {
            candidates[t_][0] = candidates[t_][k_];
            System.arraycopy(many, offset, candidates[t_], 1, left);
            offsets[t_] = 1 + left;
        }
        for (int rank = t, top = Integer.MIN_VALUE ; 0 <= --rank ; ) {
            switch(offsets[rank]) {
            case 0: // shouldn't happen?!
                break;
            case 1:
                top = 0;
                break;
            default:
                Arrays.fill(candidates[rank], offsets[rank], k, nonTopT);
                keep(rank+1, offsets[rank]);
                top = k_;
            }
            candidates[t_][k_t+rank] = candidates[rank][top];
        }
//      orderK(candidates[t_], 0);  // ??
    }
    /** place top t of up to k values in candidates[t_][0:t] */
    private void handleFew(final E[] many) {
        final int n = many.length;
        if (n == t)
            return;
        if (n < k) {
            if (1 < t) {  // fill up k values to order
                Arrays.fill(candidates[0], n, k, many[0]);
                orderK(candidates[0], 0);
            }
            System.arraycopy(many, 0, candidates[0], k - n, n);
        }
        orderK(candidates[0], 0);
        for (int p = 0 ; p <= k/2 ; p++) {  // t_ might be 0
            E tmp = candidates[0][k-p];
            candidates[0][k-p] = candidates[t_][p]; 
            candidates[t_][p] = tmp;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TopByOrderK<String> topper = new TopByOrderK<>(3, 5, null);
        String many[] = {
                "for", "int", "offset", "n", "k", "order", "apply", "many",
//              "runnersUp", "top", "candidates",
//              "offsets", "trickle", "down", "x", "z"
            };
        topper.topByOrderK(many);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(topper.candidates[topper.t_])
            .subList(topper.k_t, topper.k));
        System.out.println(topper.calls + " calls");
    }
}
```

Comment: `class [[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [[Ljava.lang.String; ([[Ljava.lang.Object; and [[Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')` ?

Comment: Sure. Otherwise: what motivates this above something very simple like an inner priority queue? It seems pretty complex.

Comment: @Reinderien Of course you can implement a priority queue, even (ab)using an *orderK()* as a comparison copying values appropriately. This will not get anywhere near *few calls to order()*. (If so inclined, you can view `candidates` as a capacity limited speciality priority queue.)

Comment: (I still wonder whether or not this is about algorithm. Short of handling just k-t fresh values in each iteration, sure this is the most simple approach…)

Comment: The edit seems like answer invalidation. Should I be worried?

Comment: (The code presented for review was in infancy when I got fed up with not getting it into shape by early November. Re-reading it during the holidays led to adding a few comments, and presenting the factored out handling of few total elements.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ... non-descendingly. */
```

I prefer "monotonic ascending", which is easily mentally shortened
to just "ascending".
Matter of taste.
Humans tend to deal better with positive definitions than negative ones.

## dead stores in ctor

```
        t_ = top -1;
        ...
        k_ = k - 1;
        k_t = k - top;
```

I don't get it.
We compute these locals, and then never use them?
Better to just elide them.

```
    int offsets[], t, t_, k, k_, k_t;
```

Oh, wait.
They *are* object attributes, so they aren't dead stores.
But, we don't like using the `this` convention in the ctor,
even when not syntactically necessary?
Recommend you add `this`, for emphasis.

I don't understand why the name `kT` isn't being used.

It's not obvious to me that *any* of these are actually needed or helpful.
But if we retain them, at least rename to `kMinusT`, `kMinus1`, `tMinus1`.

It would be a kindness to the Gentle Reader to declare
attributes in similar order to how ctor assigns them.

## verb vs. noun

(or vs. adjective)

Consider changing the signature to

```
    void keep(int numKept, numValid) {
```

## meaningful identifier

```
        int down = k_ - keep;
```

The meaning of the index `down` at this point is obscure.
Add a `// comment`, or choose a more informative name.

In general, I'm looking for a loop variant in the keep() routine.
The promise was to "distribute" values.
There's no `assert` at the end verifying that,
and I wouldn't know what to test if I wanted to add such an assertion.

Writing backwards `if (0 < keep)` expressions seems less helpful
than letting me mentally pronounce `if (keep > 0)` as "if keep positive".

Eliding `{` `}` curly braces on single-statement `if`'s
makes reading the code much harder.
I am continually feeling like I'm trusting the author
not to trick me with misleading indents.
Better to just expose the nesting structure by writing the braces.

## class invariant

We need `offsets[keep]` to be valid,
but it's unclear when that was established.
It's not a Class Invariant, since ctor didn't touch that array.
Similarly for `candidates[--keep]`.

We are only told

```
        // keep up to k values of each potential rank ...
        ...
        // ... and next free offset
```

which is not enough.

The repeated `candidates[ci] = Arrays.copyOf(many, k)` sheds
little light on what the invariant might be.
I think it was just used to allocate storage?!?

I don't see a plan written down,
that we will visit `many` in a certain order,
and prune out losing entries following a certain pattern.

```
        int offset = 1;                // used in wrap-up
```

I still don't know the *meaning* of `offset`,
and the code didn't explain it to me.

## fatal error

```
            case 0: // shouldn't happen?!
                break;
```

Throw a fatal exception here, please.
Then we will *know* it doesn't happen.

## constant that changes

```
        for (int rank = t, top = Integer.MIN_VALUE ; 0 <= --rank ; ) {
```

Up in the ctor you told us that `top` is a synonym for `t`,
and indeed we might mentally pronounce the latter as "top".
But here we're using same identifier in a different scope
to represent a different concept.

Choose a new name for the new concept.

## comments lie!

This is just wrong.

```
    /** place top t of up to k values in candidates[t_][0:t] */
    private void handleFew(final E[] many) {
        final int n = many.length;
        if (n == t)
            return;
```

The [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
is pretty clear.
We evaluate for side effects,
and the routine *shall* place `t` values into `candidates`.

It didn't.

Now, maybe the higher level application doesn't need it to.
Which suggests that the spec is wrong.
Fix the code to conform to the spec, or fix the spec.

It's unclear why {`t == 1`, `t > 1`} are distinct special cases.
It's unclear why `handleFew` would need to make more than
a single `orderK()` call, nor where its complexity is coming from.
Up at the call site I thought it would be a nice trivial helper
that makes an orderK() call and a copy.

## automated test suite

This submission doesn't have one.

```
        System.out.println( Arrays.asList( ...'
```

That's a nice print statement, sure.
But it's not self evaluating.

Crucially, it is a "big" test,
we don't see any "small" unit tests of individual component routines.

And those routines are on the complex and slightly long side.
If I could see them being exercised by
[unit](https://junit.org/junit5) tests,
I might have a greater understanding now of the corner cases they handle,
and greater confidence that they compute the right thing.

Near as I can tell, the global "found the top T entries!" assessment
was done by manually eyeballing the output,
rather than by having a component with access to global `sort()`
verify that post-condition.

Sometimes I eyeball things correctly.
I like the belt-n-suspenders backup of having an automated check.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is interesting enough. However, I fear that it attracts solutions that are over-complex, and the solution in the question seems to be complex.

Other granular issues -

You're tracking calls to `Arrays.sort`, when it would be more interesting to track comparison calls.

`int offsets[]` is C-style array syntax; you should convert to Java syntax.

`candidates = (E[][]) new Object[t][];` suffers from the usual Java generic problem of type erasure. This `Object` type leaks to your output and causes grief. You should choose one of the several type-strong ways around this problem.

### Alternative

Trusting that the implementation of [PriorityQueue](https://devdocs.io/openjdk%7E19/java.base/java/util/priorityqueue) is itself efficient (it's based on a priority heap), this can be as simple as

```java
public class TopByOrder<E> {
    public final int t;
    public final Comparator<E> comparator;
    public TopByOrder(int t, Comparator<E> comparator) {
        this.t = t;
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public PriorityQueue<E> reduce(Collection<E> in) {
        PriorityQueue<E> out = new PriorityQueue<>(t + 1, comparator);
        for (E entry: in) {
            out.add(entry);
            while (out.size() > t)
                out.remove();
        }
        return out;
    }
```

with demo code

```java
    public static class CountingComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        private int ncalls = 0;
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            ++ncalls;
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }

        public int getNcalls() { return ncalls; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountingComparator comparator = new CountingComparator();
        TopByOrder<String> topper = new TopByOrder<>(3, comparator);
        List<String> in = List.of(
            "for", "int", "offset", "n", "k", "order", "apply", "many",
            "runnersUp", "top", "candidates",
            "offsets", "trickle", "down", "x", "z"
        );
        for (String out: topper.reduce(in)) {
            System.out.println(out);
        }
        System.out.printf("Calls: %d%n", comparator.getNcalls());

    }
}
```

(a parallel `Stream` collector is also possible.)

With all of your sample inputs included, this costs 47 comparator calls. I cannot currently compare this result to your own code, since that seems to have a casting problem; but until performance becomes an overriding concern I would prefer the simpler solution.

Comment: `tracking calls to Arrays.sort()` No. Calls to instantiation parameter `OrderK<E> order`. See "the original problem": you have *no (direct) way* to compare values, none of *greater than*, *equal to*, complements thereof or logical combinations, in the strictest form, not even identity.

Comment: `choose one of the several type-strong ways around this problem` Please point me to more than one.

Answer (score 2):

As previously explained, I found the OP code to be not quite transparently obvious.
It wasn't clear to me why there needed to be so many abstractions
between the problem statement and the implemented solution.

Here is my proposed solution.

```py
def find_top_t(t: int, a: np.ndarray, k: int = K) -> np.ndarray:
    ...
    if len(a) <= t:
        sort_k(a, 0, t)
    while len(a) > t:
        for i in range(0, len(a), k):
            sort_k(a, i, k)
            a[i + t : i + k] = tombstone
        # ...
        a = np.array(list(filter(lambda x: x != tombstone, a)))
    return a[:t]
```

I count about eight SLOC.
I don't understand why we might need significantly more than that.

(Assume `tombstone` is a manifest constant,
chosen to be outside the range of interest for the application.)

---

In the interest of completeness, here
is a full implementation along with a
test suite that exercises it.

```py
# based on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287745/determine-top-t-values
# cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713266/most-efficient-way-to-get-the-largest-3-elements-of-an-array-using-no-comparison

from collections import Counter
from contextlib import contextmanager
from functools import partial
from random import shuffle
import unittest

from beartype import beartype
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st
import numpy as np

cnt: Counter = Counter()  # an event counter


@contextmanager
def count_sort_calls():
    cnt["sort"] = 0
    yield cnt


@beartype
def roll_some_numbers(n: int = 1000) -> np.ndarray[int, np.dtype[np.int_]]:
    """Produces N distinct random integers that are conveniently small."""
    # Leaving room between entries deals with pigeonhole principle & birthday paradox.
    big_n = int(1.5 * n)

    a = np.random.randint(0, big_n, 2 * big_n)
    a = np.array(sorted(set(a.tolist()))[:n])
    assert len(a) == n
    return a


K = 5


@beartype
def sort_k(a: np.ndarray, start: int, k: int) -> None:
    """Puts K elements into descending order."""
    # The "top" elements will appear at the front.
    # This is convenient for truncated displays of large arrays.
    assert 0 <= start < len(a)
    cnt["sort"] += 1

    a[start : start + k] = sorted(a[start : start + k], reverse=True)


@beartype
def find_top_t(t: int, a: np.ndarray, k: int = K) -> np.ndarray:
    assert t < K
    assert t <= len(a)
    tombstone = a.min() - 1  # sentinel value
    assert tombstone not in a  # true by construction

    if len(a) <= t:
        sort_k(a, 0, t)
    while len(a) > t:
        for i in range(0, len(a), k):
            sort_k(a, i, k)
            a[i + t : i + k] = tombstone
        # Now coalesce the survivors, shrinking the array of candidate answer values.
        a = np.array(list(filter(lambda x: x != tombstone, a)))

    return a[:t]


T = 3

_moderately_large = 2**63 - 1
# The set of all integers is very, very large,
# and cPython can model a pretty big subset of them.
# Let's restrict the ambitions of `hypothosis` to something more reasonable.
_small_integers = partial(
    st.integers,
    min_value=-_moderately_large,
    max_value=_moderately_large,
)


def shuffled(a: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    b = a.copy()
    shuffle(b)
    return b


@beartype
class TestTopT(unittest.TestCase):
    """Verifies that the Right Thing happens, in less than a second."""

    def test_roll(self) -> None:
        a = roll_some_numbers()
        self.assertLess(a[0], a[-1])

    def test_sorted_slice(self) -> None:
        a = np.array(range(8))

        sort_k(a, 2, k=3)
        self.assertEqual([0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7], a.tolist())

        sort_k(a, 2, K)
        self.assertEqual([0, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7], a.tolist())

        a.sort()
        sort_k(a, 6, K)  # Partial sort, at end of array, works as expected.
        self.assertEqual([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6], a.tolist())

    def test_top_t(self, t=T) -> None:
        a = roll_some_numbers(10)
        with count_sort_calls() as cnt:
            xs = find_top_t(t, a.copy()).tolist()
        self.assertEqual(5, cnt["sort"])
        self.assertEqual(xs, sorted(xs, reverse=True))
        self.assertEqual(xs, sorted(a, reverse=True)[:t])

    def test_with_dups(self, t=T, n=10_000) -> None:
        a = np.random.randint(0, n // 2, n)
        self.assertLess(len(set(a)), len(a) / 2)
        xs = find_top_t(t, a.copy()).tolist()
        self.assertEqual(xs, sorted(xs, reverse=True))
        self.assertEqual(xs, sorted(a, reverse=True)[:t])

    def test_imbalanced(self, t=T, num_distractors=10_000) -> None:
        with count_sort_calls() as cnt:
            a = np.array(shuffled([1] * t + [0] * num_distractors))
            self.assertEqual([1] * t, find_top_t(t, a).tolist())
        self.assertEqual(num_distractors / 2 + 12, cnt["sort"])

        with count_sort_calls() as cnt:
            a = np.array(shuffled([1] * (t - 1) + [0] * num_distractors))
            self.assertEqual([1] * (t - 1) + [0], find_top_t(t, a).tolist())
        self.assertEqual(num_distractors / 2 + 12, cnt["sort"])

    def test_010(self) -> None:
        a = np.array([0, 1, 0])  # This input vector was surfaced by hypothesis.
        self.assertEqual([1, 0, 0], find_top_t(T, a).tolist())

    @given(st.lists(_small_integers(), min_size=T, max_size=100))
    def test_with_hypothesis(self, lst: list[int]) -> None:
        a = np.array(lst)
        xs = find_top_t(T, a.copy()).tolist()
        self.assertEqual(xs, sorted(xs, reverse=True))
        self.assertEqual(xs, sorted(a, reverse=True)[:T])
```

---

EDIT

@greybeard, here is my current `pip` setup:

```
$ pip freeze
absl-py==2.0.0
aiohttp==3.9.1
aiosignal==1.3.1
alembic==1.13.1
altair==5.2.0
annotated-types==0.6.0
argon2-cffi==23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
astroid==3.0.1
asttokens==2.4.1
atomicwrites==1.4.1
attrs==23.1.0
beartype==0.16.4
beautifulsoup4==4.12.2
bitarray==2.8.3
black==23.11.0
blinker==1.7.0
blis==0.7.11
boltons==23.1.1
branca==0.7.0
Brotli @ file:///Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/brotli-split_1695989838345/work
cachetools==5.3.2
catalogue==2.0.10
certifi @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/certifi_1700303426725/work/certifi
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/charset-normalizer_1698833585322/work
click==8.1.7
click-plugins==1.1.1
cligj==0.7.2
cloudpathlib==0.16.0
cloudpickle==3.0.0
colorlog==6.8.0
comm==0.2.0
compact-json==1.6.1
confection==0.1.4
contourpy==1.2.0
coverage==5.5
cycler==0.12.1
cymem==2.0.8
Cython @ file:///Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/cython_1701025484377/work
dacite==1.8.1
dask==2023.11.0
datasets==2.15.0
decorator==5.1.1
deprecation==2.1.0
dill==0.3.7
en-core-web-sm @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=86cc141f63942d4b2c5fcee06630fd6f904788d2f0ab005cce45aadb8fb73889
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
evaluate==0.4.1
executing==2.0.1
eyed3==0.9.7
face==20.1.1
fasteners==0.19
filelock @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/filelock_1698714947081/work
filetype==1.2.0
fiona==1.9.5
flake8==6.1.0
Flask==3.0.0
fonttools==4.45.1
frozenlist==1.4.0
fsspec @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/fsspec_1697919321618/work
fuzzywuzzy==0.18.0
geographiclib==2.0
geopandas==0.14.1
geopy==2.4.1
gitdb==4.0.11
GitPython==3.1.40
glom==23.5.0
gmpy2 @ file:///Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/gmpy2_1666808689326/work
gpxpy==1.6.2
greenlet==3.0.1
haversine==2.8.0
html2text==2020.1.16
htmlmin==0.1.12
huggingface-hub==0.19.4
hypothesis==6.91.0
idna @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/idna_1701026962277/work
ImageHash==4.3.1
imbalanced-learn==0.11.0
importlib-metadata==6.8.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
ipyleaflet==0.18.0
ipython==8.18.1
ipywidgets==8.1.1
isort==5.12.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
jedi==0.19.1
Jinja2 @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/jinja2_1654302431367/work
joblib @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/joblib_1691577114857/work
jsonschema==4.20.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.11.1
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.9
kiwisolver==1.4.5
langcodes==3.3.0
Levenshtein==0.23.0
liac-arff==2.5.0
llvmlite==0.41.1
locket==1.0.0
lxml==4.9.3
Mako==1.3.0
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
markdownify==0.11.6
MarkupSafe @ file:///Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/markupsafe_1695367621021/work
matplotlib==3.7.3
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
maturin==1.3.2
mccabe==0.7.0
mdurl==0.1.2
memory-profiler==0.61.0
minio==7.2.0
mpmath @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/mpmath_1678228039184/work
multidict==6.0.4
multimethod==1.10
multiprocess==0.70.15
murmurhash==1.0.10
mypy==1.7.1
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
netifaces==0.11.0
networkit==10.1
networkx @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/networkx_1698504735452/work
nltk==3.8.1
numba==0.58.1
numbers-parser==4.4.6
numpy==1.25.2
onnx==1.15.0
opencv-python==4.8.1
openml==0.14.1
openpyxl==3.1.2
optuna==3.5.0
osmnx==1.7.1
packaging==23.2
palettable==3.3.3
pandas==2.0.3
parso==0.8.3
partd==1.4.1
pathlib-mate==1.2.1
pathspec==0.11.2
patsy==0.5.3
pendulum==2.1.2
pexpect==4.9.0
phik==0.12.3
Pillow @ file:///Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/pillow_1697423658740/work
platformdirs==4.0.0
pluggy==1.3.0
polars==0.19.18
preshed==3.0.9
prettytable==3.9.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.41
protobuf==4.25.1
psutil==5.9.6
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
py4j==0.10.9.7
pyarrow==14.0.1
pyarrow-hotfix==0.6
pyAudioAnalysis==0.3.14
pycodestyle==2.11.1
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodome==3.19.0
pydantic==2.5.2
pydantic_core==2.14.5
pydeck==0.8.0
pydub==0.25.1
pyflakes==3.1.0
pygame==2.5.2
Pygments==2.17.2
pylint==3.0.2
pynisher==1.0.10
pyo3-pack==0.6.1
pyparsing==3.1.1
pyproj==3.6.1
PySocks @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/pysocks_1661604839144/work
pyspark==3.5.0
pytest==7.4.3
pytest-cov==4.1.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-Levenshtein==0.23.0
python-snappy==0.6.1
pytz==2023.3.post1
pytzdata==2020.1
PyWavelets==1.5.0
PyYAML==6.0.1
rapidfuzz==3.5.2
referencing==0.31.0
regex==2022.10.31
requests @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/requests_1684774241324/work
responses==0.18.0
rich==13.7.0
roman==3.3
rouge-score==0.1.2
rpds-py==0.13.1
ruamel.yaml==0.18.5
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.8
ruff==0.1.6
safetensors==0.4.1
scikit-learn @ file:///Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/scikit-learn_1698225196710/work
SciPy @ file:///Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/scipy-split_1700812582578/work/dist/scipy-1.11.4-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl#sha256=5b875a53aeeb67c8451f09cb04406bae2b2ac7255cf4b820ae8098cfc1031194
seaborn==0.12.2
sentencepiece==0.1.99
shapely==2.0.2
sigfig==1.3.3
six==1.16.0
smart-open==6.4.0
smmap==5.0.1
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.5
spacy==3.7.2
spacy-legacy==3.0.12
spacy-loggers==1.0.5
SQLAlchemy==1.4.50
sqlalchemy-mate==1.4.28.4
srsly==2.4.8
stack-data==0.6.3
statsmodels==0.14.0
streamlit==1.28.2
streamlit-image-coordinates==0.1.6
sympy @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/sympy_1684180540116/work
tabulate==0.9.0
tangled-up-in-unicode==0.2.0
tenacity==8.2.3
thinc==8.2.1
threadpoolctl @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/threadpoolctl_1689261241048/work
tokenize-rt==5.2.0
tokenizers==0.15.0
toml==0.10.2
tomlkit==0.12.3
toolz==0.12.0
torch @ file:///Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/pytorch-recipe_1699313596155/work
torchvision @ file:///Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/torchvision-split_1701228065651/work
tornado==6.4
tqdm==4.66.1
traitlets==5.14.0
traittypes==0.2.1
transformers==4.35.2
typeguard==4.1.5
typer==0.9.0
types-requests==2.31.0.10
typing_extensions @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/typing_extensions_1695040754690/work
tzdata==2023.3
tzlocal==5.2
Unidecode==1.3.7
urllib3 @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/urllib3_1699933488691/work
uszipcode==1.0.1
validators==0.22.0
visions==0.7.5
wasabi==1.1.2
watchdog==3.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.12
weasel==0.3.4
Werkzeug==3.0.1
widgetsnbextension==4.0.9
wordcloud==1.9.2
xgboost==1.7.6
xlsx2csv==0.8.1
xmltodict==0.13.0
xxhash==3.4.1
xyzservices==2023.10.1
yarl==1.9.3
ydata-profiling==4.6.2
zipp==3.17.0
```

It came from this:

```
$ cat environment.yml && conda env update

name: problems

channels:
- conda-forge

dependencies:
- cython >= 0.29.34
- pip >= 23.3.1
- py-opencv >= 4.6.0
- py-xgboost >= 1.7.1
- python >= 3.11.4
- torchvision >= 0.16.1
- pip:
  - beartype >= 0.16.4
  - beautifulsoup4 >= 4.12.2
  - bitarray >= 2.8.3
  - black[jupyter] >= 23.11.0
  - dask >= 2023.11.0
  - datasets >= 2.15.0
  - evaluate >= 0.4.1
  - eyed3 >= 0.9.7
  - fasteners >= 0.19
  - flake8 >= 6.1.0
  - flask >= 2.3.2
  - geopandas >= 0.14.1
  - geopy >= 2.4.1
  - glom >= 23.5.0
  - gpxpy >= 1.6.2
  - html2text >= 2020.1.16
  - huggingface_hub >= 0.16.4
  - hypothesis >= 6.91.0
  - imbalanced-learn >= 0.11.0
  - ipyleaflet >= 0.18.0
  - isort >= 5.12.0
  - lxml >= 4.9.3
  - markdownify >= 0.11.6
  - matplotlib >= 3.7.3
  - maturin >= 1.3.2
  - memory-profiler >= 0.61.0
  - mypy >= 1.7.1
  - netifaces >= 0.11.0
  - networkit >= 10.1
  - numba >= 0.58.1
  - numbers_parser >= 3.11.0
  - numpy >= 1.25.2
  - onnx >= 1.15.0
  - openml >= 0.14.1
  - openpyxl >= 3.1.2
  - osmnx >= 1.7.1
  - palettable >= 3.3.3
  - pandas >= 2.0.3
  - pillow >= 9.5.0
  - polars >= 0.19.18
  - psutil >= 5.9.6
  - pyarrow >= 14.0.1
  - pyaudioanalysis >= 0.3.14
  - pydeck >= 0.8.0
  - pydub >= 0.25.1
  - pygame >= 2.5.2
  - pylint >= 3.0.2
  - pynisher >= 1.0.10
  - pyo3-pack >= 0.6.1
  - pyspark >= 3.5.0
  - pytest >= 7.4.3
  - pytest-cov >= 4.1.0
  - python-Levenshtein >= 0.23.0
  - pywavelets >= 1.4.1
  - roman >= 3.3
  - rouge_score >= 0.1.2
  - ruamel.yaml >= 0.18.5
  - ruff >= 0.1.6
  - scikit-learn >= 1.3.2
  - scipy >= 1.11.3
  - sentencepiece >= 0.1.99
  - spacy >= 3.7.2
  - sqlalchemy >= 1.4.47, < 2
  - streamlit >= 1.28.2
  - streamlit-image-coordinates >= 0.1.6
  - tabulate >= 0.9.0
  - transformers >= 4.35.2
  - typer >= 0.9.0
  - types-requests >= 2.31.0.10
  - unidecode >= 1.3.6
  - uszipcode >= 1.0.1
  - watchdog >= 3.0.0
  - xlsx2csv >= 0.8.1
  - ydata-profiling >= 4.6.2

...
```

Almost certainly, nearly every one of those packages is irrelevant.

I bet that `beartype` was the one you got caught up on.

Comment: (Got bitten by inaccessible packages trying to give the full implementation a spin. Can you quote input size & count (&t&k) for some non-trivial input, t > 1, 1 < k-t < 9?)

Comment: @greybeard, ummm, I thought I did that with `self.assertEqual(num_distractors / 2 + 12, cnt["sort"])`, given that we're groveling through ten thousand randomly shuffled array elements.

Comment: (`thought I did that` Probably, the DIY way. If only it ran straight away in my 3.5.2 installation. OTOH, that's the same but for constants as e.g. "the SO answer" or (presumably) [Joop Eggen's](/a/288655/93149) `determineTop()`&`determineTop2()`. The whole point was to reduce this by a significant factor - and readably so.)

Comment: `Sometimes I eyeball things correctly.` Sometimes I don't: While I never caught `nonTopT` not to work with smallish "random" input, it failed miserably with a moderate constructed Dutch flag one. Turns out I can't find a way to find a "neutral value for padding" short of running a full fledged tournament.

Comment: Bounty awarded here for test cases & means.

Answer (score 1):

It is an *abstract* logic puzzle.

When you have a function ordering 5 elements, and search the 3 highest elements, a naive solution would be:

1. start with index 0
2. order the next 5 elements from index
3. the last 3 elements of that sub-array are the current highest
4. skip the lowest 2 elements by increasing the index by 2
5. repeat till end
6. mind the number of elements

There might be a smarter solution by ordering first at indices 0, 5, 10, ... and then shoving elements together for yet another sequence of orderings.

- The naive solution above for N elements needs to call the order function N/2 times.
- The second idea would in the first sequence (partial result) need N/5 order calls, yielding a new array of N*3/5 elements, for which you could do a recursive call. The total number of calls is mathematically interesting.

My guess is, that the original question was intended to ponder about such optimization ideas, whereas you dove immediately into implementation issues.

> By the way premature jumping into implementation is a professional risk.

---

### After comment some feedback

I guess @greybeard wants some concrete code, especially on variants (?). Because stylistically the original code shows non-java background, here a rework.

The algorithm is done in `determineTop` (N/2 steps) and I made a variant with `determineTop2` where the many do-while loops add some steps.

The code in-situ (in-place) moves sub-arrays, hence for `determineTop2` it was needed to pass the array size.

```
public class PickTopByOrdering<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    public final int topSize;
    public final int orderSize;

    public int calls;

    public PickTopByOrdering(int topSize, int orderSize) {
        this.topSize = topSize;
        this.orderSize = orderSize;
    }

    /**
     * Order at the given offset orderSize elements before length.
     * @param array of all values.
     * @param length of the array considered.
     * @param offset index to start with.
     * @return the next offset after what was sorted.
     */
    private int order(T[] array, int length, int offset) {
        int end = Math.min(offset + orderSize, length);
        Arrays.sort(array, offset, end);
        return end;
    }

    private T[] determineTop(T[] array, int length) {
        calls = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += orderSize - topSize) {
            order(array, length, i);
            ++calls;
        }
        int start = Math.max(0, length - topSize);
        T[] top = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start, length);
        return top;
    }

    private T[] determineTop2(T[] arrays, int length) {
        calls = 0;
        do {
            int nextLength = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ) {
                int nextI = order(arrays, length, i);
                ++calls;
                int topI = Math.max(i, nextI - topSize);
                int moved = Math.min(topSize, nextI - i);
                System.arraycopy(arrays, topI, arrays, nextLength, moved);
                nextLength += moved;
                i = nextI;
            }
            System.out.printf("... %d -> %d, calls: %d%n", length, nextLength, calls);
            length = nextLength;
        } while (length > topSize);
        
        int start = Math.max(0, length - topSize);
        T[] top = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrays, start, length);
        return top;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PickTopByOrdering<String> topper = new PickTopByOrdering<>(3, 5);
        String[] arrays = {
                "for", "int", "offset", "n", "k", "order", "apply", "many",
                "runnersUp", "top", "candidates",
                "this", "example", "creates", "an", "instance", "which", "is", "intended", "to",
                "display", "objects", "y",
                "offsets", "trickle", "down", "x", "z"
        };
        String[] top = topper.determineTop2(arrays, arrays.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(top));
        System.out.printf("%d array element; %d calls.%n", arrays.length, topper.calls);
    }
}
```

Now you might consider `determineTop2` no win, especially with the `System.arraycopy`, but for other cases than `3, 5` say 3, 10 it might become interesting.

As said the code is just an attempt at stylistic improving all. And I am not sure this code indeed looks better.

Comment: Steps 1-6 are the basic solution, and nothing wrong with it but using that many calls to `orderk()` (handling candidates for 1st place & retiring k(5) - t(3) values each call). The basic idea to save calls is to handle candidates for 2nd place together, each call retiring (k-t+1), 3rd(k-t+2), … until a final cleanup. When doing it in phases as started in the paragraph below that numbered list, you need O(*n*) additional space.

Comment: You caught me not sufficiently reading the details & decisions. You might want to formulate your solution first more abstractly. Very interesting, if it weren't Christmas time.

Comment: I might appreciate an elaboration in your answer of how to implement that suggestion *in the code* - the "non-doc-comment" above `public void topByOrderK()` does look overly terse from where I stand now, and was fresh (here) when I started a bounty mere hours before [Reinderien answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288587/93149).

Comment: I tried, but not very successfully. Added code and a bit of style. I agree with your assessment on the complexity. In fact you probably have a better idea what would still be possible.

Comment: `not sure this code indeed looks better` (don't I recognise that feeling) `determineTop2()` sure highlights that I may have indiscriminately accumulated constraints like *neither mutation of the input nor O(n) additional space* (not put into the question purposefully) until the difficulty of implementation overwhelmed me.